# How to play .m3u8 and manage buffering?

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, http-live-streaming

I'm setting up a web page that can play from m3u8 playlist (HLS). I want to handle requests and read chunk by chunk from the server and append it to the buffer. Also clear the buffer when some chunks of the video are played. It's something similar to this example with MSE https://github.com/bitmovin/mse-demo/blob/master/index.html. Is there any possibility to do it with hls.js

Comment: What do you mean by “like this”. Do you want video to play, or are you asking for a compatible API? Hls.js is open source, so you can change it to do whatever you want.

Comment: I want to read chunk by chunk. control the size of the buffer and clear it when some chunks are played

Comment: Great, please update the original question to include this additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Hls js allows for setting a back buffer

e.g.

new Hls({liveMaxBackBufferLength: 30})